# Detecting menu item text (and ID)

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, menuitem

Code:

```
auto pMenuEdit = GetCongregationSubMenu(1);
if (pMenuEdit != nullptr)
{
    const int iSize = pMenuEdit->GetMenuItemCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < iSize; i++)
    {
        CString strMenuText;

        MENUITEMINFO sInfo{};
        sInfo.cbSize = sizeof(MENUITEMINFO);
        sInfo.fMask = MIIM_STRING | MIIM_ID;
        sInfo.dwTypeData = strMenuText.GetBuffer();
        GetMenuItemInfo(pMenuEdit->GetSafeHmenu(), i, TRUE, &sInfo);
        strMenuText.ReleaseBuffer();

        if (strMenuText == strCongregation)
        {
            // Simulate pressing the Edit Congregation menu item
            PostMessage(WM_COMMAND, sInfo.wID);
            break;
        }

        pMenuEdit->GetMenuString(i, strMenuText, MF_BYPOSITION);
        if (strMenuText == strCongregation)
        {
            // Simulate pressing the Edit Congregation menu item
            PostMessage(WM_COMMAND, sInfo.wID);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Why is it that the `pMenuEdit->GetMenuString(i, strMenuText, MF_BYPOSITION);` approach works correctly but the `GetMenuItemInfo(pMenuEdit->GetSafeHmenu(), i, TRUE, &sInfo);` approach does not? According to the debugger the text is empty.

The Microsoft documentation encourage using `GetMenuItemInfo` instead of `GetMenuString`.

My mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Text buffers in C always consist of two parts: A pointer to the beginning of the buffer and a count (in elements or bytes). The code in question never supplies a value for the `cch` field of the [`MENUITEMINFO`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-menuiteminfow) structure.

Solving this will still cause the code to fail to retrieve the menu item text because the `strMenuText` buffer is empty. You also must allocate sufficient space (e.g., by supplying a buffer size in the call to [`CString::GetBuffer()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/csimplestringt-class#getbuffer)).

The standard pattern is to discover the required length first:

```cpp
MENUITEMINFO sInfo{};
sInfo.cbSize = sizeof(MENUITEMINFO);
sInfo.fMask = MIIM_STRING | MIIM_ID;
if (!GetMenuItemInfo(pMenuEdit->GetSafeHmenu(), i, TRUE, &sInfo)) {
    // Handle error
}

UINT const required_length = sInfo.cch;
```

and use that information to allocate a sufficiently sized buffer:

```
CString strMenuText;

sInfo.dwTypeData = strMenuText.GetBuffer(required_length);
sInfo.cch = required_length + 1;
if (!GetMenuItemInfo(pMenuEdit->GetSafeHmenu(), i, TRUE, &sInfo)) {
    // Handle error
}
strMenuText.ReleaseBufferSetLength(sInfo.cch);
```